# Hibernate/JPA many to many join tables and add as multiple strings as predicate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, many-to-many, predicate

I'm trying to create a search where I fetch rows from Image with conditions 
 on columns in the Image table and keywords/tags from another table mapped via a many-to-many relationship. An image can have several tags and tags can be associated with several images.

Tables are:

```
**Image**
imageId
make
model
and so on....

**ImageTags**
imageId
tagId

**Tags**
tagId
tagName
```

Say I want to search for images with the tag "nature" the SQL would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.* FROM Images i
INNER JOIN ImagesTags it ON it.imageId = i.imageId
INNER JOIN Tags t ON t.tagId = it.tagId
WHERE t.tagName in ("city", "nature");
```

There could be more and different conditions in the WHERE clause on other columns in the Image table and therefore I've tried to build dynamic queries with Criteria API since the conditions will shift on each query. But I can't get it to work.

I've succeded with only searching for keyword:

```
    @Transactional
    public List<Image> findByKeyword(String [] tags) {
        List<Image> images = null;
        try (Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)){
            String hql = "select distinct i from Image i " +
                    "join i.tags t " +
                    "where t.tagName in (:tags)";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            ((org.hibernate.query.Query) query).setParameterList("tags", tags);
            images = query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return images;
    }
```

Now I want to add more conditions in the WHERE clause an example is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.* FROM Images i
INNER JOIN ImagesTags it ON it.imageId = i.imageId
INNER JOIN Tags t ON t.tagId = it.tagId
WHERE i.make = "Nikon" AND t.tagName in ("city", "nature");
```

I've tried to create a builder and add predicates but I can't seem to find a way to create the join.

```
CriteriaBuilder cBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Image> criteriaQuery = cBuilder.createQuery(Image.class);
Root<Image> imageRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Image.class);

predicateList.add(cBuilder.equal(imageRoot.get("imageId"), sc.getImageId()));
predicateList.add(cBuilder.equal(imageRoot.get("licenseType"), sc.getLicenseType()));

//more predicates are omitted

//Here somewhere I want to add an array or list of tags to the where clause and match that to the many-to-many relationship.

Predicate finalPredicate = cBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
criteriaQuery.where(finalPredicate).distinct(true);
org.hibernate.query.Query<Image> imageQuery = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

List<Image> images = imageQuery.getResultList();
```

Image class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Images")
public class Image implements File {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "imageId")
    private int imageId;

    @Column(name = "fileName")
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name = "filePath")
    private String filePath;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "fileSize")
    private String fileSize;

    @Column(name = "dateTime")
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

//Other attributes omitted

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "ImagesTags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "imageId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "tagId"))
    private Set<Tag> tags;

//getter and setters omitted
```

Tag class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tags")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "tagId")
    private int tagId;

    @Column(name = "tagName")
    private String tagName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "ImagesTags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tagId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "imageId"))
    private List<Image> images;
```

How do I go about to create that join and add the keywords to the "WHERE tagName IN" clause?

**Edit:**

I've changed the code to this but it doesn't seem to work anyway

```java
CriteriaBuilder cBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Image> criteriaQuery = cBuilder.createQuery(Image.class);
Root<Image> imageRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Image.class);
Root<Tag> tagRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Tag.class);
Join<Image, Tag> join = imageRoot.join(Image_.TAGS);

List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
predicateList.add(cBuilder.equal(imageRoot.get("width"), 2000));
predicateList.add(cBuilder.in(join));
predicateList.add(cBuilder.equal(tagRoot.get("tagName"), tags[0]));

Predicate finalPredicate = cBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
criteriaQuery.select(imageRoot);
criteriaQuery.where(finalPredicate).distinct(true);
org.hibernate.query.Query<Image> imageQuery = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

List<Image> images = imageQuery.getResultList();
```

**Edit 2**

Trying with this:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Image> criteriaQuery = cBuilder.createQuery(Image.class);
Root<Image> imageRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Image.class);
Root<Tag> tagRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Tag.class);
Join<Image, Tag> join = imageRoot.join(Image_.TAGS);

List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();

predicateList.add(cBuilder.in(join));
predicateList.add(cBuilder.or(cBuilder.equal(tagRoot.get("tagName"), "träd")));

Predicate finalPredicate = cBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
criteriaQuery.select(imageRoot);
criteriaQuery.where(finalPredicate).distinct(true);
org.hibernate.query.Query<Image> imageQuery = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

List<Image> images = imageQuery.getResultList();
```

But it produces a (to me) very strange query to the database:

```
select distinct generatedAlias0 
from Image as generatedAlias0,
     Tag as generatedAlias1 
inner join generatedAlias0.tags as generatedAlias2 
where (generatedAlias2 in ()) and (
            generatedAlias1.tagName=:param0 
        ) 
select distinct image0_.imageId as imageId1_1_,
            image0_.author as author16_1_,
            image0_.dateTime as dateTime2_1_,
            image0_.description as descript3_1_,
            image0_.fileName as fileName4_1_,
            image0_.filePath as filePath5_1_,
            image0_.fileSize as fileSize6_1_,
            image0_.height as height7_1_,
            image0_.licenseType as licenseT8_1_,
            image0_.location as location9_1_,
            image0_.make as make10_1_,
            image0_.model as model11_1_,
            image0_.noOfAllowedUses as noOfAll12_1_,
            image0_.price as price13_1_,
            image0_.resolution as resolut14_1_,
            image0_.width as width15_1_ 
        from
            Images image0_ 
        inner join
            ImagesTags tags2_ 
                on image0_.imageId=tags2_.imageId 
        inner join
            Tags tag3_ 
                on tags2_.tagId=tag3_.tagId cross 
        join
            Tags tag1_ 
        where(tag3_.tagId in ()) and tag1_.tagName=?
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html#join-java.lang.String-

Comment: @JBNizet thanks! I've updated with some changes I've made but it still doesn't work.